# how to select form id with jquery before sending out a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several forms on my page with different IDs. Each form has a submit button and should be handled separately.

So the if i specify the form id the code below works fine, since I have x amount of forms which are not known in advance I need to make this script more general.

```
$(function() {
  $('#form1').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'post.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#form1').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        console.log($('#form1').serialize());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I am able to get the form id with the scrpt below, but I cannot figure out how to combine with the script above.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var myId = this.id;
  alert(myId);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a reference to `this`, so that you can access the `form` element that triggered the `submit` event within the callback:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  var self = this;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'post.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(self).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      console.log($(self).serialize());
    }
  });
});
```